# Title text attribute of navigationBar dose not work. IN SWIFT

Tags: swift

I changed title text attribute just like this:

[image]

But I think that is not applied:

[image]

I really want to know why it is.

And this is my settings:

[image]

Comment: What is your navigation bar's tint color?

Comment: my bar tint color is BrandBlue and this is named color.

Comment: Same settings working at my code. Can you share rest of your attribute inspector?

Comment: really thank you for your effort   I update my image just before.

Comment: share your code here

Comment: I find my problem. I think if I set bar tint at attribute inspector, then all the setting that I set about title text attribute is ignored. and I didn't anything that related to that part in my code.now I focus on why that happen.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You must change your `navigation controller's` attributes, not your view controller.[image]

Hope it helps...